# Does it follow from field axioms that the sum of multiplicative identity with its additive inverse is the additive identity?

Tags: field-theory

In other words, is it true (and if so why) that 1-1=0? (1 and 0 being multiplicative and additive identity elements)?

---

**Some background.** I'm reading Mathematical Background: Foundations of Infinitesimal Calculus by K. D. Stoyan and I was trying to solve an exercise which asks to prove that -1*a=-a.  This exercise hints at a possible way to solve it being to assume that (1-1)*a=0.  If I assume that 1-1=0, then I've no problems with the proof, but I don't know whether this applies to any field, or only some of them (such as real numbers).

Comment: Isn't that the definition of an additive inverse?

Comment: @Hayden oh my! Yes it is, well, that was silly indeed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't that the definition of an additive inverse? –  Hayden

Providing an accept-target since this question appears to have been answered in the comments.